# Second SQL Server connection inside UDF with Update Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr, msdtc

Ok, this is a bit complicated so I'll try to simplify it as much as possible.  I have a SQL Server View with an Instead-Of Trigger. The Trigger calls a CLR UDF (C#), call it MyUDF. MyUDF attempts to open a second connection with a literal connection string, i.e.,

```
using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(newConnString)) { ...
```

I have confirmed that the connection string is good.  I have also confirmed that the UDF works fine outside of the Update Trigger.  However, when called by the Update Trigger I get the DotNet error shown below.  I even tried enabling DTC according to this KB with no luck: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx

I need to open the second connection due to permissions. The current connection may not have sufficient permissions to perform the necessary queries so I cannot use `"context connection=true"`

Question: is there a way to open a second connection under these circumstances?

Here is the DotNet Error (SQL Server 2008 Standard, Windows 2008 x86, DotNet 4):

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MyUDF": 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction context in use by another session.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.PropagateTransactionCookie(Byte[] cookie)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at UserDefinedFunctions.MyUDF(SqlString data)
```

Comment: I found the answer: Include the following in the Connection String: `"enlist=false"`. Now what I'd like to ask is if anyone can explain why that works?